# How to convert 100.00 to 100 and 100.23 to 100.23 dart

Tags: flutter, dart, double

How to convert 100.00 or 100.0 to 100 and if the number is 100.23 it should keep it as the same 100.23.

In dart, I tested these functions floor() and round() they return 100 even if the number is 100.23.

How to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you get a better answer, you can do something like the following steps:

```
double value = 100.32739273;
String formattedValue = value.toStringAsFixed(2);

print(formattedValue);

if (formattedValue.endsWith(".00")) {
  formattedValue = formattedValue.replaceAll(".00", "");
}

print(formattedValue);
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to implement something like this but I am searching if there is a built function in dart which can do the same.

Answer (score 4):

By using the intl package of flutter to format the number. please refer below

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart' as intl;

  @override
  void initState() {
    var valueFormat = intl.NumberFormat.decimalPattern();
    print(valueFormat.format(100.234));
    print(valueFormat.format(100.00));
  }
```

OutPut

```
I/flutter ( 5364): 100.234
I/flutter ( 5364): 100
```

Comment: there is a problem here, if you try to send valueFormat.format(4458.3333333333) it return 4,458.333 and this is bug, it comma and dot. how to solve it?

Comment: Comma and dots are standard format, you can resolve by use the RegExp.

Answer (score 2):

```
double input1 = 100.00;  //100
double input2 = 100.0; //100
double input3 = 100.23; //100.23

RegExp regex = RegExp(r"([.]*0)(?!.*\d)");

String str = input1.toString().replaceAll(RegExp(r"([.]*0)(?!.*\d)"), "");
```

Comment: stolen from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55152175/how-to-remove-trailing-zeros-using-dart

Comment: I didn't even check that and how can you say I've stolen from that and I didn't even check your comment.