# How to round double to 2 decimal places and remove trailing zeros?

Tags: flutter, dart, rounding, truncate

I couldn't find a way to round double to 2 decimal places and remove trailing zeros in Dart. I found a way to round but it doesn't work if I try to truncate trailing zero.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
double x = 5.0;
double y = 9.25843223423423;
double z = 10.10;

print(x); //Expected output --> 5
print(y); //Expected output --> 9.26
print(z); //Expected output --> 10.1
```

EDIT:

I found a way to solve the first 2 print statements above. I thought I should add it for whoever is searching it.

```
String getFormattedNumber( num ) {

  var result;
  if(num % 1 == 0) {
    result = num.toInt();
  } else {
    result = num.toStringAsFixed(2);
  }
return result.toString();
```

}

Answer (score 8):

Rounding a floating point number according to a decimal representation doesn't make much sense since many decimal fractions (such as `0.3`) [can't be exactly represented by floating point numbers anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). (This is inherent to all floating point numbers and is not specific to Dart.)

You can, however, try to make *string* representations of your number pretty. [`num.toStringAsFixed`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/num/toStringAsFixed.html) rounds to the specified number of fractional digits.  From there, you can use a regular expression to remove trailing zeroes:

```dart
String prettify(double d) =>
    // toStringAsFixed guarantees the specified number of fractional
    // digits, so the regular expression is simpler than it would need to
    // be for more general cases.
    d.toStringAsFixed(2).replaceFirst(RegExp(r'\.?0*$'), '');

double x = 5.0;
double y = 9.25843223423423;
double z = 10.10;

print(prettify(x)); // Prints: 5
print(prettify(y)); // Prints: 9.26
print(prettify(z)); // Prints: 10.1

print(prettify(0)); // Prints: 0
print(prettify(1)); // Prints: 1
print(prettify(200); // Prints: 200
```

Also see [How to remove trailing zeros using Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55152175/how-to-remove-trailing-zeros-using-dart).

Comment: This one is working correct than the one you mentioned other one

Answer (score 2):

Here is sample code what you want.

1. multiply by 10^(count of number after point)
   if count of number after point is 2
   9.25843223423423 -> 925.843223423423
2. round 1)'s result
   925.843223423423 -> 926
3. divide by 10^(count of number after point)
   926 -> 9.26

[image]

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  double x = 0.99;
  double y = 9.25843223423423;
  double z = 10.10;

  print(x); //Expected output --> 5
  print(y); //Expected output --> 9.26
  print(z); //Expected output --> 10.1
  
  print(customRound(x, 2));
  print(customRound(y, 2));
  print(customRound(z, 2));
  
  for(var i = 0.01 ; i < 1 ; i += 0.01) {
    print(customRound(i, 2));
  }
}

dynamic customRound(number, place) {
  var valueForPlace = pow(10, place);
  return (number * valueForPlace).round() / valueForPlace;
}
```

Comment: This does not work for most floating-point values. Try it with all the values for 0.01 to 0.99 incrementing by 0.01. Failure rate is over 90%.

Comment: @user207421 Hm... let me know what it is wrong with changed code that tested with from 0.01 to 0.99.

Comment: What is wrong is that you are *printing* with restricted precision. The floating point *values* have more in the cases I refer to. This is inevitable because base-10 and base-20 are incommensurable.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way is using the Flutter `maths` library.

```
// ROUND NUMBERS TO 2 DECIMAL PLACES
  double roundNumber(double value, int places) {
    num val = pow(10.0, places);
    return ((value * val).round().toDouble() / val);
  }
```

This function would help you do for any decimal place you want.

Then you can use it this way:

```
double num1 = roundNumber(12.334456789, 2);
print(num1);
```

should print:
`: 12.33`