# How to hide decimal value when it is = 0

Tags: flutter, dart, double

I am currently trying to render the price value of products using a widget in Flutter.
To do so, I pass the state and render it in the argument from the corresponding widget.
What I need to achieve is to hide the 2 decimals of my Double type priceValue and show them if they are != to 0.

Like so, if state.priceValue = 12.00 $ => should show 12
if  state.priceValue = 12.30 $ => should show 12.30

Answer (score 3):

```
String removeZero(double money) {
  var response = money.toString();

  if (money.toString().split(".").length > 0) {
    var decmialPoint = money.toString().split(".")[1];
    if (decmialPoint == "0") {
      response = response.split(".0").join("");
    }
    if (decmialPoint == "00") {
      response = response.split(".00").join("");
    }
  }

  return response;
}
```

Edit: I added to check if the string contains a decimal point or not to avoid index out of bounds issue

Comment: you can also do  price.value.toString().replaceAll(".00", "")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
String price = "12.00$"

print(price.replaceAll(".00", ""));
```

Or refer to this: [How to remove trailing zeros using Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55152175/how-to-remove-trailing-zeros-using-dart)

```
double num = 12.50; // 12.5
double num2 = 12.0; // 12
double num3 = 1000; // 1000

RegExp regex = RegExp(r'([.]*0)(?!.*\d)');

String s = num.toString().replaceAll(regex, '');
```

But the second option will remove all trailing zeros so `12.30` will be `12.3` instead

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately this wont work since price is a Double, not a String.

Answer (score -4):

Hello you could use an extension like that:

```
extension myExtension on double{
 String get toStringV2{
  final intPart = truncate();
  if(this-intPart ==0){
   return '$intPart';
  }else{
   return '$this';
  }
 }
}
```

To use the extension:

```
void main() {
 double numberWithDecimals = 10.8;
 double numberWithoutDecimals = 10.00;
 //print
 print(numberWithDecimals.toStringV2);
 print(numberWithoutDecimals.toStringV2);
}
```